# How to normalize email field value in Django REST Serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to Django in general so please do not judge me harshly.

I have a custom User model and I use DRF for user profile creation. I normalize the email in the **create_user** (method of the BaseUserManager). I cannot find the way how to also normalize the value of an email field in the API Serializer. Basically, if I pass an email that already exists in the database, but just with capital letters in the domain, it will go through the Serializer's validation, however it will hit an Integrity Error after:

`duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_user_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(email@example.com) already exists.`

Here is a shortened version of my **UserManager** method:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        #some validation logic
        #...
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    #other stuff...
```

Here is a **Serializer** itself:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {k: {'write_only': True} for k in fields}

    #some password validation...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = models.User.objects.create_user(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            password=validated_data['password']
        )
        return user
```

Here is the **view**:

```
class UserCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [field-level-validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) in serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {k: {'write_only': True} for k in fields}

    def validate_email(self, value):
        norm_email = value.lower()
        if models.User.objects.filter(email=norm_email).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not unique email")
        return norm_email
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I know what you mean with this validation, although I need to normalize email field value (from email@EXAMPLE.com to email@example.com) in order to do validation. Otherwise, it still goes through unique validation if I pass an email that already exists but just with a domain being capitalized. How can I access the email field value and perhaps convert it to lower case prior to validation and saving in the user model?

Comment: I added your logic to the validator, try it. You can change the `value.lower()` to your  normalize_email method.

Comment: Alright! Thanks a lot for your experience! It works ;)  But in general, is it normal practice to do this task in the Serializer or it can be done also in the view?

Comment: glad to help you, better in serializer, you may use  it in many views.

Comment: That is not a correct answer. Technically, SamDaniels@test.com and samdaniels@test.com are different email addresses while SamDaniels@test.com and SamDaniels@Test.Com are the same.

`django.contrib.auth.base_user.BaseUserManager.normalize_email`

Comment: the question is ` how to also normalize the value of an email field **in the APISerializer**.` But you catch only a peace of the question. Replace `value.lower()` with your function and that's it.